# regex for password check that doesn't require special characters

Tags: regex

I can't seem to find a regex to use for a website sign-up form that doesn't require users to enter certain characters.

I need a regex which will allow only the following:

```
a-z
A-Z
0-9
*#_-
```

There doesn't have to be a number, no required capitals, no required special characters.  Spaces are not allowed.

The minimum length is 8, max is 30 but I'm handling that in another part of the code.

Comment: In what regex variety? Perl, .Net, JavaScript, PCRE? There are differences between the implementations. Your question is the equivalent of "Give me a function that will do this" without specifying what language you're using.

Comment: You said you couldn't find a regex to use, but the fact that 4 identical answer sprung up within seconds of each other has determined that you didn't look hard enough.

Comment: Learn to google before you ask such questions

Comment: WHAT!? You are regex-ing the password? Saying no to spaces? (maybe at the beginning and end of the string is okay...) Note to self: don't sign up on @spock99's web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9*#_-]{8,30}$
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try to match this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9*#_-]{8,30}$
```

How it works:

- everything between `^` and **$** means that the **entire** input has to match the following pattern.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9*#_-]` matches `a-z` or `A-Z` or `*` or `#` or `_` or `-`
- `{8,30}` will need the previous rule to match at least `8` times, at max `30` times.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do what you need in most flavours of regex parser:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9*#_-]{8,30}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9*#_-]{6,20})$
```